# Null pointer exception Sliding Menu Fragment View

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am attempting to update my main activity to support toolbar and a more material navigation drawer from this example on on Androidhive http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

This all worked before trying the conversion.  Help or guidance is greatly appreciated

I am getting this in my error log.

```
03-04 21:43:23.658  12635-12635/com.nmthemes.allthethemes E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nmthemes.allthethemes, PID: 12635
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nmthemes.allthethemes/com.nmthemes.allthethemes.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.nmthemes.allthethemes.MainActivity.setTitle(MainActivity.java:207)
            at com.nmthemes.allthethemes.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:196)
            at com.nmthemes.allthethemes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
```

Here is my Main Activity.  I have also commented the lines that are throwing the errors.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);


        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        /* Extras, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        */

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            /* *****line 110 **********/
            displayView(0);
            /**************************/
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new IconsFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new WallpapersFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ZooperFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new WatchFacesFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FeaturedFragment();
            break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new FeaturedDetailFragment();
                break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);

            /* *****line 196 **********/
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            /*************************/

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        /* *****line 207 **********/
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        /**************************/
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

My layout for the main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        ></include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">
    </FrameLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"  
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="176dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryDarkText"/>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimaryLight"
                    android:text="ThemeCenter"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nmthemes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimaryLight"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="by NMThemes"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Pretty sure I've gotten my issues worked out with this.  I have to do a build and if it all sorted, I will post the solution below.  It mostly stemmed from not having  'setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)' after i implemented my toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your `MainActivity` class using `AppCompatActivity`.

Then change the following lines:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

With:

```
assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And this line inside `setTitle()` function:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
```

To:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention but similar changes need to be made to onDrawerOpened() & onDrawerClosed() functions, or your app will crash on opening the drawer